# Best practice for authenticated docker pulls for proprietary software

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-registry

I'm running an open-core software company as an "indie hacker". Some users freely download the open source version, some other pay for the advanced version and need to be authenticated before they can access the software.

Distributing docker images of the open source version is easy with Docker Hub.

Now I would like to distribute the non-free version as well.

Is there a way to generate per-customer access tokens in order to "paywall" pulls, and possibly tell who and when pulled what image?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use
[Private repositories](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#private-repositories)
for the paid version of your software as a solution.

You get one private repository for free with your Docker Hub user
account. If you need more private repositories,
you will need to upgrade your Docker Hub plan.

You would then give access only to paid customers, and have a complete
record of all pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically looking for are solutions on how to distribute commercial software through container images.

In summary, there are a few concepts and philosophies on how to accomplish this.

1. With Docker Hub you can create tokens or invite your customer as a user to your team, but this has some cost expectations and only scales to a certain limit.

   The suggested solution for you from Docker would be to join the Docker Verified Publisher (DVP) program and **publicly** distribute your software via Docker Hub with the primary goal of growing your developer audience. Based on your question and your product, I assume this is not what you are looking for.
2. Another solution would be for you to push your software image to your client's registry. While this sounds like a smart solution, it has a lot of scalability pitfalls along the way, like access control, user management and registries on private networks.
3. Probably the best solution for your situation would be to host a dedicated container registry instance. Pay attention, that container registries are not created equal, so choose an ISV Friendly Container Registry to programmatically manage the container registry and create user accounts or generate access tokens based on subscription or payment status.

   Interface with a subscription/payment management system, CRM, ERP via an API is a must in such a scenario. Besides the above, there are other aspects that may be useful, such as a custom domain, obvious Web UI, and auditing capabilities.
   There is an article about [Distributing Commercial Software Through Container Images](https://container-registry.com/posts/distributing-commercial-software-through-container-images/) with Harbor that goes into the nitty gritty details if you want to dive into that topic.